# Apache Spark, how can I apply the same function to 15k GraphFrame graphs at a time?

Tags: python, apache-spark, graph, pyspark

I have 15k graph object created using GraphFrame. Those graphs are pretty small. I just need to apply shortest path and certain other algorithms on each graph. My current implementation is I use a for loop to loop through all 15k graphs.

I am think to somehow construct a RDD that has each graph as its item. In such case, I can just put all the algorithms I need to apply in a user-defined function and use map function of RDD to apply this function on each graph. It would be much more efficient I guess.

But the problem is how can I create such RDD?

Answer (score 0):

To speed-up your process I suggest you put your graphs in a `list` and use parallel map, for example:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def your_algos(p):
    # your code

your_graphs = [list_of_graphs]

p = ThreadPool(number_of_workers)
results = p.map(your_algos, your_graphs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically, i am using Apache Spark which is supposed to distribute the work. If I use ThreadPool, there would be no need to use Spark.